# Most apps crashing after Galaxy S4 update to 4.4.2 (with SQLite exceptions)

Tags: updates, 4.4-kitkat, crashes, ota-update

I just updated my (stock firmware) Galaxy S4 from 4.2.2 to 4.4.2 using Kies and now most apps crash when I start them.

When I look into the stack trace, the reason for all apps is the same: an SQLiteException with the message: "Could not open the database in read/write mode"

Is anybody else getting this, or know a fix?

Comment: Have you tried booting into recovery, and clearing the cache and the Dalvik cache?

Comment: Yes, it didn't have any effect

Comment: Sounds like it could be caused by the userdata partition being mounted read-only, which could be the result of a corrupted filesystem. A factory-reset would fix this if that's the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Well, annoyingly I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

A factory reset did the trick. Thanks Dan Hulme